# Redirect Blog Posts

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have hundreds of blog posts that need to be redirected due to a site redesign.  Current the URL for each blog item contains a number followed by the name of the post.  For instance, www.mysite.com/2199-this-is-the-blog-post-name.   I want to redirect all of the posts to new directories such that the URL will appear as www.mysite.com/new-directory/2199-this-is-the-blog-post-name.

What I want to know is what is the easiest way redirect these.  I would like to know if there is a way that any string starting with a number, for example 2, could then be redirected (I am not worried about over non-blog content URL that may start with a 2).  I have tried several ReWriteCond/ReWriteRule but have yet to find anything that works.

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in your htaccess

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]+.+)$ /newdir/$1
```